# Почему при переносе комментариев в чат некоторые деформируются до неузнаваемости?

Tags: дефект

Вопрос весь уместился в шапку, осталось показать картинками.

[Было](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/450363/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8E/450384?noredirect=1#comment461253_450384):

> Дорогая Галина! Первое впечатление -- самое верное. После сорока лет
>   корректорского труда Вы вовсе даже не случайно споткнулись об этот
>   противоестественный оборот. Наработанная десятилетиями интуиция не
>   подвела Вас. "Кидая их падалью" -- это плохой стиль. Это ненужная
>   вычурность. КГАМ, как говорит молодёжь. – Michael_1812 2 часа назад
>
> У, негодяй. Корректором обозвал. А што я тебе сделала? Диплом редактора у меня пылился с незапамятных времён, а Перестройка дала
>   флаг в руки: играй, дитя, пока играется (читай: редакторствуй, коль
>   кому охота с тобой дело иметь). Так что таки да - редактор-то я исчо
>   молоденький... Хочешь поговорить о стихах - милости прошу (только
>   ЛОшка там уже выдана): *Можете ли Вы пересказать “сюжет”
>   ахмадулинского стихотворения, наполненного архаизмами и
>   церковнославянизмами?* - ссылка не уместилась, приди по поиску. –
>   Galina Avanesova 2 часа назад

[Стало](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92343/discussion-between-galina-avanesova-and-michael-1812) (в чате):

> Michael_1812 Дорогая Галина! Первое впечатление - самое верное.
>   ***После этого даже не случайно споткнулись об этом противоестественный оборот. Вы работали десятилетиями.*** "Кидая их
>   падалью" - это плохой стиль. Это ненужная вычурность. КГАМ, как
>   говорит молодёжь.
>
> Галина Аванесова
>   16.4k У, негодяй. Корректором обозвал. А што я тебе сделала? ***Диплом был написан с незапамятными временами, и Пересматривал флаг в
>   руках:*** играй, дитя, пока играется (читай: редакторствуй, коль кому
>   охота с тобой дело иметь). ***Что ты хочешь - редактор, чтобы я
>   исчерпал себя молодым ...*** Хочешь поговорить о стихах - милости
>   прошу (***только у тебя там уже есть***): Можете ли ***вы пересмотреть***
>   «сюжет» ахмадулинского стихотворения, наполненного ***архаизмом*** и
>   церковнославянизмами? - ссылка не уместилась, приди по поиску.
>
> ---

Постскриптум: скриншоты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в чате тем временем...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Галина, с Новым годом! Проблема решилась?

Answer (score 1):

Галина, честно говоря, не вижу выделенных вами фрагментов в чате и в комментариях. Вы уверены, что проблема существует?

Comment: Аэр, может, не видите потому, что они не совпадают? М.: *После сорока лет корректорского труда Вы вовсе даже не случайно споткнулись об этот противоестественный оборот. Наработанная десятилетиями интуиция не подвела Вас.* Этот же текст в чате: *После этого даже не случайно споткнулись об этом противоестественный оборот. Вы работали десятилетиями.* Я: *Так что таки да - редактор-то я исчо молоденький*. То же в чате: *Что ты хочешь - редактор, чтобы я исчерпал себя молодым*. И у других я - при переносе общения в чат - наблюдаю подобные кракозябры. Они не коснулись только совсем коротких реплик.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova так в чате все так же, как и в комментариях под оригинальным постом... может, пришлете скриншоты или уточните ссылки?

Comment: Скриншоты могу. А куда прислать? Дать ещё один ответ?

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova можете отредактировать вопрос, можете добавить ответ — на ваш выбор )

Comment: Сделано. И напоминаю: то же самое безобразие творится при переходе в чат у других пользователей, если комментарий превышает некое количество знаков, скажем: больше строки-полутора.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova разберемся, спасибо!